# Can't Install Gradle Cloudbees Plugin to Maven Local

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle, cloudbees

First off, I don't have enough reputation to post all the links, so sorry. Not my choice.

I'm trying to use Spring Boot with Cloudbees and according to [this tutorial](https://github.com/msgilligan/springboot-cloudbees-hello) I need to build the Gradle Cloudbees plugin locally and install it to my local Maven repository.

Following the Maven-Apache instructions at Guide to installing 3rd party JARs I ran this command at the terminal:

```
mvn install:install_file -Dfile=/Users/aharris/Downloads/gradle-cloudbees-plugin-master/gradle-cloudbees-plugin-master-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
    -DgroupId=org.gradle.api.plugins -DartifactId=gradle_cloudbees_plugin 
    -Dversion=0.1.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -X
```

Here is the result:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 10:31:09-0700)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.8.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/aharris/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /Users/aharris/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for /Users/aharris/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:pom:1: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix install from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix install to org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin from POM org.apache.maven:standalone-pom:pom:1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.225s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 26 18:12:46 MST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'install_file' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1 among available goals install, install-file, help -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoNotFoundException: Could not find goal 'install_file' in plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1 among available goals install, install-file, help 
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:267)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:235)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException
```

Visiting the help page on the last line leads me to believe the 'mvn' command doesn't know what 'install_file' means.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's `mvn install:install-file` (rather than `install_file`), but I'm pretty sure the intent is to use *Gradle* to install the plugin to the local Maven repository (`gradle install`).

Comment: Thanks Peter, it is install-file. Maybe I need glasses.